# How to use annotated (alias) field on the left of values as part of group by (i.e. values) clause in django using ORM?

Tags: python, django

Having challenge to get a summarized result by using django ORM utilizing an annotated field then apply values with that alias into the values (group by) and followed by other annotations to complete the aggregated field

```
Sample data:

>>>
>>> models.Sale.objects.values().first()
{'id': 93, 'sales_order': 'SON4000006', 'transaction_date': '2020-05-04 00:00:00', 'customer_name': 'Customer No2', 'delivery_note': 'DN200006', 'vehicle_number': 'T101AAA', 'tax_invoice': 'TI900006', 'product_name': 'Pro Cememnt', 'quantity': '100', 'total_value': '50000', 'quantity2': None, 'total_value2': None, 'destination': 'Zambia', 'agent_id': None, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 6, 48, 26, 59719, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 9, 6, 48, 26, 59719, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
>>>
>>>
>>> models.Document.objects.values().first()
{'id': 27, 'ref_number': '2019 MATARE75/251', 'description': None, 'doc_type': 'Exit', 'file': 'docs/SKM_Sales20042214362_Msp5YxV.pdf', 'sale_id': 85, 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 25, 16, 11, 24, 847574, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'updated_at': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 25, 16, 11, 24, 847574, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
>>>
>>>
>>>


>>>
>>> qs1=models.Sale.objects.annotate(docs_count=Count('docs'), complete=Case(When(docs_count=3, then=True), default=False, output_field=BooleanField())).values('destination', 'complete').annotate(count=Count('id'), qty=Sum('quantity'), value=Sum('total_value')).order_by('destination','complete')
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> print(qs1.query)
SELECT 
    "sales_sale"."destination", 
    CASE WHEN COUNT("sales_document"."id") = 3 THEN True ELSE False END AS "complete", 
    COUNT("sales_sale"."id") AS "count", 
    SUM("sales_sale"."quantity") AS "qty", 
    SUM("sales_sale"."total_value") AS "value" 
FROM "sales_sale" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "sales_document" ON ("sales_sale"."id" = "sales_document"."sale_id") 
GROUP BY "sales_sale"."destination"
ORDER BY "sales_sale"."destination" ASC, "complete" ASC
```

Expected output is:

```
SELECT 
    "sales_sale"."destination", 
    CASE WHEN COUNT("sales_document"."id") = 3 THEN True ELSE False END AS "complete", 
    COUNT("sales_sale"."id") AS "count", 
    SUM("sales_sale"."quantity") AS "qty", 
    SUM("sales_sale"."total_value") AS "value" 
FROM "sales_sale" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "sales_document" ON ("sales_sale"."id" = "sales_document"."sale_id") 
GROUP BY "sales_sale"."destination", CASE WHEN COUNT("sales_document"."id") = 3 THEN True ELSE False END
ORDER BY "sales_sale"."destination" ASC, "complete" ASC
```

Other information:

```
Django 3.0.2
Python 3.7
sqlite database
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The latter is, as far as I can see not valid SQL, since you are both aggregating and grouping on the same expression.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What would be ideal to group by both "complete" alias and the destination column